# yum is not finding any mirror sites

Tags: yum

Yum seems unhappy on a couple of the machines on my network but it's fine on others.

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.lax.hugeserver.com
 * epel: dl.fedoraproject.org
 * extras: centos-distro.1gservers.com
 * updates: mirror.hostduplex.com
http://mirror.lax.hugeserver.com/centos/5.11/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.hmc.edu/centos/5.11/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
. . .
http://centos.blazar.mx/5.11/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout: <urlopen error timed out>
Trying other mirror.
repo id                               repo name                                                                     status
base                                  CentOS-5 - Base                                                               3,667
epel                                  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                6,428
extras                                CentOS-5 - Extras                                                               266
updates                               CentOS-5 - Updates                                                              974
repolist: 11,335
```

Clearing the yum cache doesn't help.

```
# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
```

Yes, this machine can curl sites on the web so this isn't a network problem.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because CentOS 5 is now EOL and you need to configure special [archive respositories](http://vault.centos.org/).

Time to upgrade to CentOS 7.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem on centos mirrors

Comment: What problem do you get? Are you still running CentOS5? If yes: Why?